# difficulty in solving the total differential equation $cos(2x+2y+z)(dx+dy)+ cos(x+y)cos(x+y+z)dz =0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Finding difficulty in solving the total differential equation: $$cos(2x+2y+z)(dx+dy)+ cos(x+y)cos(x+y+z)dz =0.$$

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: will taking z as a constant and putting dz =0 work??

Answer (score 0):

By using the cosine product identity we can rewrite the differential as
$$\cos(2x +2y +z)\left[dx +dy +\frac{1}{2}\cos(z)dz\right] = 0.$$
Can you solve it from here?